# ContentManager.Create does nothing

Tags: orchardcms

I am trying to build a service in Orchard that allows me to create content through a custom form on a page. The service and the content type definitions look fine to me, but somehow, eventhough I don't get any errors or other signs in the Orchard log files, creating new content using the IContentManager does nothing for me.

### Parts involved

The controller accepting the form values

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateSopViewModel viewModel)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var shape = _shape.CreateContent();
        shape.Header = _shape.Parts_Title(Title: "New item");

        // Add the original fields to the shape.
        shape.Title = viewModel.Title;
        shape.Description = viewModel.Description;
        shape.InitialComments = viewModel.InitialComments;

        return new ShapeResult(this, shape);
    }

    // Store the new procedure in the database
    _service.CreateContentItem(
        viewModel.Title,viewModel.Description,viewModel.InitialComments);

    // Redirect the user back to the homepage.
    return Redirect("~/");
}
```

The service that contains the CreateContentItem method:

```
public void CreateContentItem(string title, string description, string initialComments)
{
    // Initialize a new content item based on the SOP type
    var customPart = _services.ContentManager.New<MyCustomPart>("CustomContentType");

    customPart.Description = description;
    customPart.Identifier = BuildIdentifier(title);
    customPart.ContentItem.As<TitlePart>().Title = title;

    _services.ContentManager.Create(customPart.ContentItem);
}
```

The content part + record

```
public class MyCustomPart: ContentPart<MyCustomPartRecord>
{
    [Required]
    public string Identifier
    {
        get { return Record.Identifier; }
        set { Record.Identifier = value; }
    }

    [Required]
    public string Description
    {
        get { return Record.Description; }
        set { Record.Description = value; }
    }
}

public class MyCustomPartRecord: ContentPartRecord
{
    public virtual string Identifier { get; set; }

    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}
```

The migration

```
SchemaBuilder.CreateTable(typeof(MyCustomPartRecord).Name, table => table
    .ContentPartRecord()
    .Column<string>("Description")
    .Column<string>("Identifier"));

ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("StandardOperationalProcedurePart", builder => builder
        .Attachable(true));

ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("CustomContentType", builder => builder
    .DisplayedAs("Custom Content Type")
    .WithPart("TitlePart")
    .WithPart("MyCustomPart")
    .Creatable(true));
```

### Question

Again, I don't get any errors, not in the log and not in Visual Studio. However, my new content item doesn't get created or at least, I can't see it in the admin section of the site under Content.

What is going on and how can I debug this behavior?

Comment: Do you also have a StorageFilter for your record in a handler?

Comment: Yeah, I have and after turning up the logging I discovered that infact it does insert records into the database. Even more bizarre, when I ask the ContentManager for the content type using a query I get items back. The admin UI doesn't show it however and that's bothering me.

Comment: The content type not being creatable can cause this, but I see you have it, so I have no further idea unfortunately...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem, which was solved when I used the overloaded `Create` method taking a `VersionOptions` enum value:

`content.Create(customPart.ContentItem, VersionOptions.Published);`

This should work even if the content item is not creatable, as mine isn't.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. In my case the item did appear eventually, but not right away.

The solution for me was to do:

```
_contentManager.Flush();
```

Comment: This solution is useful only when you need the new content within the same HTTP request. I didn't, but it still a useful suggestion.

Comment: I can't find `Flush`!?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue, in my case it was that I actually had an error in the database (trying to put 100+ characters into a field that would only hold 100!).

I found the error I was getting (null id in Orchard.Indexing.Models.IndexingTaskRecord entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs) ), actually masked the issue. I had to go hunt in the logs to find the real problem.

So anyway, my advice is if you see that contentmanager.create seems to be doing nothing, and any errors don't seem to help, check the logs carefully.  They can be found in the logs sub-folder of the appdata folder in the main Orchard.Web project. Because as I've found in the last 48 hours, often the answer is there.